# Eclipse doesn't show output from multiple methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

As a fairly new programmer and one just starting to study Java. I figured what better project to start with, than a calculator? The issue I'm having is printing output for things outside of the main method, as illustrated below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator extends Calculator_Assets {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Choose One!");

    System.out.println("1. Addition\n");

    System.out.println("2. Subtraction\n");

    System.out.println("3. Multiplication\n");

    System.out.println("4. Division\n");

    //prints out the users input, not their mathematical selection
String word = newInput.nextLine();
if (word.equals("1")) 
        System.out.println("You have chosen Addition!");


else if (word.equals("2"))          
        System.out.println("You have chosen Subtraction!");
else if (word.equals("3"))
        System.out.println("You have chosen Multiplication!");
else if (word.equals("4"))
        System.out.println("You have chosen Division!");
    //Break here, to input integers




}
public static void operands() {
    String num1 = newInput.nextLine();
    String num2 = newInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter two numbers to add:");
}
}
```

The output "Enter two numbers to add:" doesn't appear in the console.

PS: How can I improve my code structure to make it look neater? What's the industry standard?

Comment: It won't appear if you don't call the method. Only the main method is executed at runtime.

Comment: You never call the operand() method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't see you calling the method in main.
operands();   //that will call the method

Secondly, you might want to take the string "word" to the method.
Use this instead of operands();

```
operands(word); //this says "run method operands, and make the stored variable word also useful for this new method"
```

and then instead of public static void operands() {

```
public static void operands(String word) { //we have the input word from our main, and now in the parantheses we can put how we would like to call this variable (and declaring it) , you can name it different than in the main
```

Answer (score -1):

An improvement for you could be this. The code is still not very good (as i've used 2 times if (choose == 1/2/3/4), while thats basically not needed (you can put it in once) But to keep ur structure i did it that way.

```
import java.util.*;


class test{
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Choose\n 1. Addition\n 2. Subtraction\n 3. Multiplication\n 4. Division\n");
    int choose = sc.nextInt();



    if (choose == 1) 
    { 

            System.out.println("You have chosen Addition!");
    }

    if (choose == 2) 
    {      

            System.out.println("You have chosen Subtraction!");
    }

    if (choose == 3)
    {

            System.out.println("You have chosen Multiplication!");
    }

    if (choose == 4)
    {

            System.out.println("You have chosen Division!");
    }

    operands(choose);

}

public static void operands(int choose) {
    System.out.println("Enter two numbers to add:");
    int number1 = sc.nextInt();
    int number2 = sc.nextInt();

    if (choose == 1) { 

            int answer = number1 + number2;
            System.out.println(answer);
    }

    if (choose == 2)   {    
            int answer = number1 - number2;
            System.out.println(answer);
    }

    if (choose == 3) {
            int answer = number1 * number2;
            System.out.println(answer);
    }

    if (choose == 4) {
            int answer = number1 / number2;
            System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

}